# Appropriate usage, Difference and Exclusivity in installing packages using: npm, bower, ionic, cordova

Tags: npm, ionic-framework, bower, cordova-plugins, package-managers

Yes, I'm aware this has been asked before but the questions were asked in a manner that didn't give me the answer to find out the **appropriate usage** and if each package manager had **exclusive packages that couldn't be found on another**.

I understand that the ionic framework has these three frameworks/package managers underneath it and I can obtain the same package into my package making any of these same calls.

```
npm install        [mypackage]
bower install      [mypackage]
ionic plugin add   [mypackage]
cordova plugin add [mypackage]
```

I also understand that they rely on each other like so.

```
Parent>Child [The framework above the other you would need to install the other]

npm>bower
npm>ionic
npm>cordova
npm>ionic[contains cordova]
```

However from what I've seen so far I don't find any packages that are exclusive to one or the other and was wondering

**1. Are there some Packages/Plugins that are exclusive to one package manager?**

**2. Is it better to make a different call depending on workspaces?**

Answer (score 0):

npm- It is called as network packet manager it is just like installing a software or package from terminal without using GUI
bower-It will be used to install the required libraries in our project
cordova plugin add/Ionic plugin add these both commands are same there is no difference between them, but we are using ionic  plugin add because we are using Ionic framework.

Having any queries, reply back